# Remove space between the beginning and the end of xml tag

Tags: java, regex, xml, string

I need a regex to remove the spaces between the beginning and the end of xml tags.
For example:
Someone create the xml and send it to me, so i can validate, sign and send to a webservice.

To do this i need to remove the spaces between the beginning and the end of the tags:

`String xmlString = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><car><name>Beatle </name>"
        + "<doors>2</doors><drivers><driver><name> Guilherme</name></driver>"
        + "<driver><name>Leonardo </name></driver></drivers></car>";

xmlString = xmlString.replaceAll("> ", ">");
xmlString = xmlString.replaceAll(" <", "<");`

Is there a way to turn this two replaces into one with regex?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do this safely with regular expressions. In particular, any CDATA block will likely break things. You're better off using a parser, especially since you presumably want to validate the document anyway.

Comment: @chrylis Can you give me an example to use in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
(<[^/][^>]*>) +| +(<\/[^>]+>)
```

(In Java, this should be used like `String pattern = "(<[^/][^>]*>) +| +(<\\/[^>]+>)";`)

And apply the following replacement string:

```
$1$2
```

Check *Replace*, *Global*.

Tested against:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><car><name>Beatle </name>
<doors>2</doors><drivers><driver><name> Guilherme</name></driver>
<driver><name>Leonardo </name></driver></drivers></car>`

Output:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><car><name>Beatle</name>
<doors>2</doors><drivers><driver><name>Guilherme</name></driver>
<driver><name>Leonardo</name></driver></drivers></car>`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
(>) | (<)
```

You can use `|` `or` operator and replace by `$1$2`.Done in 1 regex.

Comment: I've made a test using this pattern at [link](http://www.regexp.com.br/). if i  pass $1, when there is only space before the end tag, like <tag>sadas </tag> it changes to <tag>sadas/tag>